# NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I need to get back the localized format for hours and minutes. The hours works as expected but the minutes returns "m"? Why is it not returning "mm"?

```
let locale = NSDateFormatter().locale

NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("HH", options: 0, locale:locale)
//Returns "HH" in US English and "H时" in Chinese (Simplified)

NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("mm", options: 0, locale:locale)
//Returns "m" for both???
```

Comment: *Probably* because you wouldn't display minutes alone with a leading zero (but I am speculating). Why don't you create the template from "HH:mm" ?

Comment: I am creating a time selection where the hours and minutes are set by different UI elements. First is in the HH format, the other in the mm format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470)?

```
let date: NSDate = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)

components.hour = 20
components.minute = 10

if let newDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.stringFromDate(newDate)
}
```

Here again as function to retrieve the value you need:

```
func formattedTimeString(unitToSet: NSCalendarUnit, selectedValue: Int, template: String) -> String?
{
    let date: NSDate = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)

    if unitToSet == .CalendarUnitHour
    {
        components.hour = selectedValue
    } else
    {
        components.minute = selectedValue
    }

    if let newDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components) {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate(template, options: 0, locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())

        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(newDate)
    }

    return nil
}

if let hours: String = formattedTimeString(.CalendarUnitHour, 22, "HH")
{
    println(hours) // prints 22
}

if let minutes: String = formattedTimeString(.CalendarUnitMinute, 33, "mm")
{
    println(minutes) // prints 33
}
```

Also available as [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ezcoding/2aece094d6787db14ff4), if you have further questions.

Comment: Yep, but that's not what I am after. I want the hour and minute components separately.

Comment: What do you mean by separately? You are using different UI Elements which set the hour and then the minute separately right? Why don't you keep a reference to the selected values and update everything when you need it?

Comment: In my designs, the numbers are animating. If the hours are changed, the hours UI element is "rolling" to whatever number it is being set to, hence it can't be a string with both hours and minutes in one. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It can. You just have to know which one to pick... Anyway, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Right, that mostly did the trick. The only thing now is that 22 needs to turn 10 if the locale uses AM/PM format rather than a 24 hour clock. Any idea what that would entail in your solution? I got back 22 even on en_US region format. I can probably work this out myself so i'll mark this as an accepted answer in the meantime. Thanks.

Comment: AM/PM is user defined and you can't change it. From the docs:
> _In iOS, the user can override the default AM/PM versus 24-hour time setting. This may cause NSDateFormatter to rewrite the format string you set._